# Parse files in a directory that contain a match to a set of strings - pull line with match to new file

Tags: regex, python-3.x, set, python-requests, glob

I need to parse through a directory of *multiple excel files* to find matches to a *set of 500+ strings* (that I currently have in a set).

If there is a match to one of the strings in an excel file, I need to *pull that row out into a new file*.

Please let me know if you can assist! **Thank you in advance for the help!**

The directory is called: All_Data

The set is from a list of strings in a file (MRN_file_path)

My code:

```
MRN = set()
with open(MRN_file_path) as MRN_file:
    for line in MRN_file:
        if line.strip():
            MRN.add(line.strip())

for root, dires, files in os.walk('path/All_Data'):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith('.xlsx'):
            filepath = os.path.join(root, name)
            with open(search_results_path, "w") as search_results:
                if MRN in filepath:
                    search_results.write(line)
```

Comment: What is `line` in the last line of your example code? What is `search_results`?

Comment: I just edited the code - search_results is the name of the file I am dumping the matched lines to.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't actually read the .xlsx files. As far as I know, there isn't anything in native Python to read .xlsx files. However, you can check out [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) and see if that helps. Here's a solution which reads all the .xlsx files in the specified directory, and writes them into a single tab-delimited txt file.

```
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook

MRN = set()
with open(MRN_file_path) as MRN_file:
    for line in MRN_file:
        if line.strip():
            MRN.add(line.strip())

outfile = open(search_results_path, "w")

for root, dires, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith('.xlsx'):
            filepath = os.path.join(root, name)
            # load in the .xlsx workbook
            wb = load_workbook(filename = filepath, read_only = True)
            # assuming we select the worksheet which is active
            ws = wb.active
            # iterate through each row in the worksheet
            for row in ws.rows:
                # iterate over each cell
                for cell in row:
                    if cell.value in MRN:
                        # create a temporary array with all the cell values in the matching row.
                        # the 'None' check is there to avoid errors when joining the array
                        # into a tab-delimited row
                        arr = [cell.value if cell.value is not None else "" for cell in row]
                        outfile.write("\t".join(arr) + "\n")
outfile.close()
```

If a tab-delimited output isn't what you're looking for, then you can adjust the second last line to whatever fits your needs.

Comment: Thank you!! I executed the code and I am creating an output file (Output.txt) and I am getting no errors but there is no data appearing in my output file. Do you know why this could be?

Comment: The only time things will be written to the output file is if the cell's value is in the set of strings to match (MRN in this example). It could be possible that your strings don't match the cell values completely, which is what is happening in the line `if cell.value in MRN`. That might be due to case sensitivity, whitespace, or something else, so you may have to play around with some regex.

Comment: Hey Kevin, thanks again! I have a test built in there so at least 1 match should come up but it's not. The strings are all numerical so there should be no issues with case sensitivity. I'm not sure where to go from here, I am still getting no output.

Comment: You're welcome. Do you have some sample inputs and strings you could add to the question? It could make things easier to test and debug.